# Deploying to Azure SQL Database inside a Azure Failover Group

Tags: sql, azure, dacpac

I'm unable to deploy may dacpac package when connecting to Azure SQL Failover
Group.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: Could not deploy package.
Error SQL72016: Cannot open Failover Group "****.database.usgovcloudapi.net" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

The same works if I use either primary or secondary server instead. There are some [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421495/cant-deploy-to-azure-sql-database-inside-a-azure-failover-group-using-dacfx) about the "master" database being unavailable since it isn't replicated by design.

Has this been resolved or is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you try connecting to <your-failover-group-name>.database.windows.net,1433 using the same credentials ? How are you trying to deploy dacpac, what are you using for connection ?

Comment: I'm using the server's admin account to <your-failover-group-name>.usgovcloudapi.net,1433

Answer (score 0):

As per product group, logins will not be moved, we need to create logins in the Secondary as well.